# Product custom option delete while edit product programmatically

Tags: magento2, product, custom-options, programmatically

I have added a custom option in product from the back-end.

---

### [image]

After that when I tried to update the product **`programmatically`** but Facing an issue: When I edited the product all the custom options of product has been deleted.

---

### [image]

It removes all options while editing a product. I have checked all entries in the database that's also get deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the solution of this.
Not great solution but it's working fine for me.

I have first getting all options of the product before save.

```
protected function getProductOptions($productObj)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customOptions = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($productObj);

        $options = [];
        if($customOptions->count() > 0) {
            foreach($customOptions as $customOption) {

                $optionsValue = [];
                $customOptionValues = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Value')->getValuesCollection($customOption);
                if($customOptionValues->count() > 0) {
                    foreach($customOptionValues as $customOptionValue) {
                        $optionsValue[] = array(
                            'record_id' => $customOptionValue->getRecordId(),
                            'title' => $customOptionValue->getTitle(),
                            'price' => $customOptionValue->getPrice(),
                            'price_type' => $customOptionValue->getPriceType(),
                            'sort_order' => $customOptionValue->getSortOrder(),
                            'sku' => $customOptionValue->getSku(),
                            'is_delete' => 0,
                        );                
                    }
                }


                $sku = $customOption->getSku();
                $title = $customOption->getTitle();
                $type = $customOption->getType();
                $price = $customOption->getPrice();
                $price_type = $customOption->getPriceType();
                $record_id = $customOption->getRecordId();

                $options[] = array(
                    'sort_order' => $customOption->getSortOrder(),
                    'title' => $title,
                    'price_type' => $price_type,
                    'price' => $price,
                    'type' => $type,
                    'values' => $optionsValue,
                    'is_require' => 1,
                );

            }
        }

        return $options;        
    }
```

After that I have added that all options after save the product.

```
protected function addProductCustomOptions($product, $productOption) 
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $product->setHasOptions(1);
        $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
        foreach ($productOption as $arrayOption) {
            $option = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')
                    ->setProductId($product->getId())
                    ->setStoreId($product->getStoreId())
                    ->addData($arrayOption);
            $option->save();
            $product->addOption($option);
        }

    }
```

Now I am getting my all product options same as before.

Comment: How you manage products option while you are trying to import new products with custom options? Your code is working fine when there are already products available with custom options.

Answer (score 1):

We can say it was an issue with older version less than 2.4.x

That fix has been available with [PR](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/29349/files/d1e5d9a89aafdaca85f788a39ccd80611de3fb6c)

> ```
> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Option/SaveHandler.php
> ```

```
public function execute($entity, $arguments = [])
    {
        if ($entity->getOptionsSaved() || !$entity->getCanSaveCustomOptions()) {
            return $entity;
        }
```

Recommending to use the latest version or use relevant patch or you may override the logic by plugin or preference.

Comment: Still this issue is not fixed in Magento 2.4.2, if found any solution, please let me know.